# VBA overflow error with byte variables

Tags: vba, variables, excel

Can someone please explain why the following code would generate an overflow error in VBA when the recipient of the operation `c` is an `Integer`?

```
Dim a As byte, b As Byte  
Dim c As Integer  
a = 3: b = 100  
c = a * b
```

or does it mean that every operation involving 'Byte` variables would have to yield only a result be between 0 and 255 regardless of the recipient variable type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> or does it mean that every operation involving byte variables would have to yield only a result be between 0 and 255 regardless of the recipient variable type

Yes, because Bytes only hold values from 0 to 255, multiplying 3 x 100, you are passing (overflowing) its capacity, even though afterwards you are passing the result into an integer.

Because you are multiplying two Bytes together, VBA assumes the result to be a Byte too. It is only after the calculation that the result is *then* cast to an integer.

To get around this, you must cast at least one of the variables. This lets VBA know that it must make room for a larger result:

```
Dim a As Byte, b As Byte
Dim c As Integer
a = 3
b = 100
c = a * CInt(b) ' <-- Cast b as Integer to prevent Overflow error
```