# Overflow Error with Byte Data Type when the Value provided within its limits

Tags: excel, vba

for some reason, I'm getting an Overflow error (Runtime error:6) even though the byte data type value is within its limits. Here's the code:

```
Sub Var_Dec2()
Dim myByt As Byte '0 to 255
myByt = 255
Range("a24").Value = myByt * 1000
End Sub
```

Please help me understand this!!! thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined `myByt` as Byte, so when you do `myByt * 1000` you are getting another Byte number. And it must be a value between 0 and 255.

**Edit:** Actually, when you multiply 2 defined variables diferent, the output will be the *largest* type.

```
myLong = 1000
Range("a24").Value = myByt * 1000 'will raise error
Range("a24").Value = myByt * myLong 'will NOT raise error
```

**UPDATE 2:** Found this old question about same issue:
[VBA overflow error with byte variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995459/vba-overflow-error-with-byte-variables)

Comment: You meant to say that one Variable output value must not get the other Variable output value... right?

but mybyt*100 is working without any issues

Comment: Are you sure? In other languages the operation is promoted to integer and the result casted to the target variable, a `Value` element of a cell, which is long int I believe.

Comment: @mrk777 check updated answer.  The output will be the biggest type **defined**

Comment: @PaulOgilvie In other languages could be, but in VBA I think is not. The exact technical reason of this, I do not  know it, but I would say *it wokrs* like that after experience and some code testings.

Comment: Indeed, as you show, VBA takes the largest int of the variables, but ignores the type/size of literals.

Comment: It uses the Integer type for the literal (100 or 1000 for example). `mybyt * 100` will fit into an `Integer`, which is the resulting operator data type, so no error. `mybyt * 1000` will not, hence the overflow. If you specify the literal as a Long using `1000&` then it will work, since the resulting operator type is `Long` now not `Integer`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using a defined variable for the multiplication, you can just cast the byte data into long data for the calculation

```
Sub Var_Dec2()
    Dim myByt As Byte '0 to 255
    myByt = 255
    Range("A24") = CLng(myByt) * 1000
End Sub
```